# How to extract a text in double quotes inside div with XPath

Tags: python, xpath

(Sorry - I frequent just *Stack Overflow em Português* but got no help this time, and my English isn't so good. But let me try:)

I want to extract a text that is variable conform the time of the soccer game basically, but I can't find this with XPath. And frankly, the HTML of the site doesn't help so much.

The HTML is this:

> ```
> <div class="style_title__3UbkX"> 
>     "name_team_home"
>     "0"
>     <span>x</span>
>     "2"
>     "name_team_away"
> </div>
> ```

If the teams are Barcelona and Real Madrid, it appears like this in HTML code:

> ```
> <div class="style_title__3UbkX">
>     "Real Madrid"
>     "0"
>     <span>x</span>
>     "2"
>     "Barcelona"
> </div>
> ```

And in the site it will appear in the center of the site something like

> | Real Madrid 0 x 2 Barcelona |
> | --- |

(I can't send images yet)

But it can be different in different minutes of the game, but it doesn't matter, so if the Real Madrid team score a goal, the number in quote will change to 1.

This HTML for me is so strange because it's not separated. Is like this, it's a real copy from the site. I'm not used to use HTML, so I don't know if it's is normal tbh.

I want to extract the numbers in quote, 0 and 2 for a variable, but my code doesn't find this information. I'm trying to use XPath methods, like in this code, but both can't find the information:

```
goals_h = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//*[@id="root"]/div/section/section/main/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/text()[2]').text

or

goals_h = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,  
    '//*[@id="root"]/div/section/section/main/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/text()[2]'))).text
```

I want the value in `text()[2]` in this XPath.

Someone know how to resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you can target the element and get all of the text then you could just use string parsing to extract those bits you need. I think you're going to have to do a combination of string parsing and xpath to get what you want the way that you want it.

Comment: Can you share the url?

Comment: Ok, nice idea, i'll try it

Comment: I can't share the url because it's a paid site, with login and pass to have access for this stats :(

Comment: `This HTML for me is so strange because it's not separated` like `<home name='Real' score='0' /> <away name='Barça' score='2' />`? Somehow, XHTML hasn't quite taken off, yet. I fail to parse `a text that is variable conform the time of the soccer game basically` with any confidence - can you get help, if from machine translation?

Comment: i agree with you, i dont know much about html, but this site is so strange looking for anothers sites because of it, i don't know how but the stats changes for every minutes if the score changed, even being a text in quotes. I did something using Excel, but it's not the correct form to do, i still want to do something with python

Answer (score 0):

For a good solution, I would do what James Oltmans suggests above.

For a BAD solution:

`normalize-space(substring-after(substring-after(//div[@class="style_title__3UbkX"]/text()[1], "\n"),"\n"))`

and

`normalize-space(substring-before(substring-after(//div[@class="style_title__3UbkX"]/text()[2], "\n"), "\n"))`

You would still have to remove the quotation marks with string processing, but this is, after all, a bad solution.

Comment: i did something with excel forms and vba code, it's not a correct way but it's works, so in the moment was ok, but i'm trying to do what the guys above said

Answer (score 0):

This XPath will return `2`:
`"substring-after(substring-before(normalize-space(//*[@id='root']/descendant::div[span[.='x']]/text()[2]),'\" \"'),'\"')"`

General form:

```
substring-after(
  substring-before(
    normalize-space(haystack),
  needle-before),
needle-after)
```

Tested on this html fragment

```
<div id="root">
<section>
    <div>
            <div class="style_title__3UbkX">
                "name_team_home"
                "0"
                <span>x</span>
                "2"
                "name_team_away"
            </div>
    </div>
</section>
</div>
```

With lxml:

```
>>> from lxml import html
>>> tree = html.parse(r'/home/lmc/tmp/test.html')
>>> result = tree.xpath("substring-after(substring-before(normalize-space(//*[@id='root']/descendant::div[span[.='x']]/text()[2]),'\" \"'),'\"')")
>>> result
'2'
```

The other XPath is:
`"substring-before(substring-after(normalize-space(//*[@id='root']/descendant::div[span[.='x']]/text()[1]),'\" \"'),'\"')"`

Result:
`0`
General form:

```
substring-before(
  substring-after(
    normalize-space(haystack),
  needle-after),
needle-before)
```

The key is this XPath
`"normalize-space(//*[@id='root']/descendant::div[span[.='x']]/text()[2])"`
that returns
`"2" "name_team_away"`
then the substring to 'cut' the string is
`" "`

Comment: thank you LMC, i'm trying to do it this wekeend, and after i go back to tell you what happens. I already did something, but using excel forms and the vba, not in python. Excel helped me for the moment but it's not a correct way.

Comment: The xpath should work in almost any app/language, hope it works for you. In case of trouble, start by using the xpath inside `normalize-space()` and then add the rest.